# Encode HTML entities but ignore HTML tags - in PHP

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I have a string that might look like this

```
$str = "<p>Me & Mrs Jones <br /> live in <strong style="color:#FFF;">España</strong></p>";
htmlentities($str,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',false);
```

How can I convert the text to HTML entities without converting the HTML tags?

*note: I need to keep the HTML intact*

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1364933/1032370

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer: I would not encode any entities, except for <, > and &. That said, if you really want this, do this:

```
$str = '...';
$str = htmlentities($str,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8',false);
$str = str_replace(array('&lt;','&gt;'),array('<','>'), $str);
```

Comment: I would go with this too, most of the times there isn't a need to encode " and '. And stuff like €, á, é should be handled by Unicode already.

Comment: @TravisO: I expect the input to be valid HTML already. If he has 2 > 5 in his markup, this won't be handled just like <<<img src="" &&&& /> isn't handled correctly.

Comment: Your third line should read: $str = str_replace(array('&lt;','&gt;'),array('<','>'), $str);

Answer (score 2):

The problem, that you face, is that under circumstances you already have encoded '`<`' and '`>`' in your text, so you have to filter them out after conversion.

This is similar to Evert's answer, but adds one more step to allow for content like `1 < 2` in your markup:

```
$str = htmlentities($str,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8',false);
$str = str_replace(array('&lt;','&gt;'),array('<','>'), $str);
$str = str_replace(array('&amp;lt;','&amp;gt'),array('&lt;','&gt;'), $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

A good answer was post by [Pascal MARTIN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138475/pascal-martin)

See this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364933/htmlentities-in-php-but-preserving-html-tags)

To resume, you can use this piece of code, to retrieve a list of correspondances `character => entity` :

```
$list = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
unset($list['"']);
unset($list['<']);
unset($list['>']);
unset($list['&']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use htmlentities before, but it seems like a bit more robust version of urlencode (which I use a lot).  You might want to try:

`htmlentities(strip_tags($str,ENT_COMPAT),'UTF-8',false);`

Just as a little nugget, if you want to preserve `<br>` as standard carrage returns, you could do this:

`htmlentities(strip_tags(str_replace("<br>","\n",$str,ENT_COMPAT)),'UTF-8',false);`

I know that's something I sometimes like to do.

Good Luck.

Comment: urlencode and htmlentities do different things: urlencode makes the string valid to put in a url (e.g. turning & into %26), htmlentities escapes a sring for use in HTML (e.g. turning < into &lt;).

Answer (score -1):

If you mean to convert only text, then try this:

```
$orig = "<p>Me & Mrs Jones <br /> live in <strong style="color:#FFF;">España</strong></p>";
$str = strip_tags($orig);

$str = htmlentities($str,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',false);
```