# Truncate string with HTML tags in it

Tags: php, html, string, tags, php-5.3

I have a string which contains HTML tags. I'm looking for a piece of code that would let me truncate this string to:

- have 100 characters length,
- contain no image tags (`<img />`).
- include other HTML tags (except image tag),
- that 100 characters lenght should not include white spaces and HTML tags characters.

For example, the string is:

```
<img>Something</img><b>Just an Example</b> Plain Text <br><a href="#">stackoverflow</a>
```

So the result should be:

**Just an Example** Plain Text stackoverflow (its a link).

As a result we have around 35 words (except white-space).

I tried solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1193500/1469208), but didn't get required result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you already try some of PHP templates modules/frameworks that help to do that?

Comment: How did the result differ from what you require?

Comment: @Herbert - I am getting string which also counting html-tags and white-spaces in total word length. So when i truncating the string for only 100 words i get 80 words and rest count was for white-space and html tags. Please give me some hint by answering the question. Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielGartz - My  project is on Symfony framework, does it help?

Comment: Try this: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @GabrielGartz - thanks .. but is there any other to way to do it without using any plugin?

Comment: You can use regular expression, but you can't ensure the results. `s/<[a-zA-Z\/][^>]*>//g`

Comment: Maybe [this blog post](http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/cut-html-string-without-breaking-the-tags/) will help. Apparently, the code is taken from CakePHP, but CakePHP isn't required.

Comment: [Ignore tags][1]
There's your answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946057/encode-html-entities-but-ignore-html-tags-in-php

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946057/encode-html-entities-but-ignore-html-tags-in-php][1]

There's your answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946057/encode-html-entities-but-ignore-html-tags-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate text containing HTML, ignoring tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/truncate-text-containing-html-ignoring-tags)

Comment: There are several subtasks to this task.  You have not asked a narrow question.  We need to see your actual implementation of your attempt so that we can fix the incorrect parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a function. Here's mine -- `AbstractHTMLContents`. It has two parameters:

- input HTML content,
- limit.

Here's the code:

```
function AbstractHTMLContents($html, $maxLength=100){
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    $printedLength = 0;
    $position = 0;
    $tags = array();
    $newContent = '';

    $html = $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $html);

    while ($printedLength < $maxLength && preg_match('{</?([a-z]+)[^>]*>|&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;}', $html, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $position))
    {
        list($tag, $tagPosition) = $match[0];
        // Print text leading up to the tag.
        $str = mb_strcut($html, $position, $tagPosition - $position);
        if ($printedLength + mb_strlen($str) > $maxLength){
            $newstr = mb_strcut($str, 0, $maxLength - $printedLength);
            $newstr = preg_replace('~\s+\S+$~', '', $newstr);  
            $newContent .= $newstr;
            $printedLength = $maxLength;
            break;
        }
        $newContent .= $str;
        $printedLength += mb_strlen($str);
        if ($tag[0] == '&') {
            // Handle the entity.
            $newContent .= $tag;
            $printedLength++;
        } else {
            // Handle the tag.
            $tagName = $match[1][0];
            if ($tag[1] == '/') {
              // This is a closing tag.
              $openingTag = array_pop($tags);
              assert($openingTag == $tagName); // check that tags are properly nested.
              $newContent .= $tag;
            } else if ($tag[mb_strlen($tag) - 2] == '/'){
          // Self-closing tag.
            $newContent .= $tag;
        } else {
          // Opening tag.
          $newContent .= $tag;
          $tags[] = $tagName;
        }
      }

      // Continue after the tag.
      $position = $tagPosition + mb_strlen($tag);
    }

    // Print any remaining text.
    if ($printedLength < $maxLength && $position < mb_strlen($html))
      {
        $newstr = mb_strcut($html, $position, $maxLength - $printedLength);
        $newstr = preg_replace('~\s+\S+$~', '', $newstr);
        $newContent .= $newstr;
      }

    // Close any open tags.
    while (!empty($tags))
      {
        $newContent .= sprintf('</%s>', array_pop($tags));
      }

    return $newContent;
}
```

It seems, it gives result expected by you.

Comment: One of the best solutions to this problem, I ever met. Great job!

Comment: duplicate answer to a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1193598/2419960