# Why does PHP function strip_tags() removes data that is not tags? How to avoid this?

Tags: php

This code:

```
$input = 'I love <3 PHP!';
echo strip_tags($input);
```

Outputs:

```
I love
```

Is there a PHP function (or anyone's custom function) which would remove only tags (that means properly closed tags), not everything preceded by `<` ?

Comment: say hello to htmlpurifier: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does PHP function strip_tags() removes data that is not tags?

It errs on the side of security.

> How to avoid this?

If you are expecting text input, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to *escape* `<` characters (and a few others) instead of removing them.

Comment: I don't want to do that, because I'm passing the user input to PHP markdown, which creates comments from ``> this text``, like here on StackExchange. When I convert the input to special chars, this doesn't happen anymore. I need to find the middle ground. I'll accept any answer which solves this situation.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946057/encode-html-entities-but-ignore-html-tags-in-php

Comment: why can't you pass the user input direct to the markdown parser? if it's a decent parser it should do all the sanitisation for you.

Comment: @Spudley: it's not supposed to remove tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), it will still show  tags, but converted to html entities

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5 the Tidy extension is usually available in most compiled binaries. It is not 100% effective but could help you in this case. Tidy tries to close all unclosed HTML tags in a string. With it closed you could then ignore the wanted tag. You would then need to strip out the final tag that tidy put in.

[Tidy documentation](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)

```
$str = tidy("I <3 PHP");

// second param ignores the closed tag <3>
$str = strip_tags($str, '<3>')

$str = str_replace('<3>', '<3', $str);

echo $str;
```