# Special Spanish Characters not displaying, Codeigniter MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8

Spanish special characters are not displaying correctly, a word like: 'Árbol' is displayed like '�bol'.

1) Text in database is saved correctly. 'Árbol' looks perfect on database.

2) If I insert a new word, eg. 'Tétrico', it is saved correctly on database.

I've been experiencing this problem since I moved the project to another server, on localhost (Ubuntu server) works perfect.

I've tried everything reading similar questions:

- View files are encoded in UTF-8 without BOM.
- header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
- In my.cnf, I've added the lines:

  init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'

  character_set_server=utf8

It just doesn't work.

What else can I do?

I've replicated changes that I did on localhost (because project works perfect here, everything's displaying correctly) to new server, but nothing's changed.

Comment: The data you're outputting is not actually UTF-8 encoded. I'd be guessing the Codeigniter database configuration is not set to utf8.

Comment: decese, it is: on config.php $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'; and in database.php $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8'; $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';

Answer (score 6):

I'm not exactly sure why, but I had this on html views and it wasn't working.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

By reading this post, I found an alternative answer:

[How to display special characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699037/how-to-display-special-characters-in-php)

So I had to change the header of html files. I put this line:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

and it works perfect now.