# Troubles with text encoding on spanish

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, character-encoding

I have a webpage that has some text on spanish and some words have accents and spanish characters, on the webpage i have a datatable retrieving information, the thing is, when i use the tag:

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulybR.png

it displays correctly the text on the Footer, with accents, but the information from the datatable gets a lot of trash chars.

but then again, if i use the tag:

```
<meta charset="utf8"> or
<meta charset="latin1_spanish_ci">
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/abhwR.png

i get the datatable information correctly, but the text on the footer now gets the trash chars.

Already tried with different encodings and combinatios of them and still not working.

Tables and  database are on latin1_spanish_ci collate

Comment: pick one charset, recommended utf8

Comment: what are you using, MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle? other?

Comment: inclined to close dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: hello, its mysql, would utf8 still recognize the accents?

Comment: I forgot also, which API, `mysql_`, `mysqli_` PDO are you using to connect with?

Comment: hello, im using mysqli_

Comment: check out the link that Dagon left you above. Your answer may very well be in there. Usually passing utf8 through the connection before querying solves it. and yes, utf8 for accents.

Comment: ok....so... where are we with this; problem solved?

Comment: not yet, im still working on it :)

Comment: should i re do the database with ut8 collation for tables and database?

Comment: well i have redone databse, made everything utf8, still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use the unicode encoding for the letters with diacritical marks.

Answer (score 0):

please take this solution :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- Your HTML file can still use UTF-8-->
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
   /*Just for your server-side code*/
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
  echo "àè";
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>`
```

I got it from here [How to display special characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699037/how-to-display-special-characters-in-php)

Comment: sorry, this gives me the same result as before.

Comment: change àè by your string and check with same code and let me know

Comment: oooh ok, let me check.

Comment: I mean , copy this code and save it as test.php page , then try to see the result when you take out header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'); and when you keep it

Comment: its work fine for me , please show me your code , you can edit your question and add your code

Answer (score 0):

- What bytes to you have in the source?  (Provide hex)
- What did you use when calling `mysqli_set_charset()`
- What is the `CHARACTER SET` on the column in the table?
- What `<meta ... charset...>` did you have.

Please state all for, plus any output.

To show the hex from PHP, use

```
$hex = unpack('H*', $text);
echo implode('', $hex);
```

To show the hex in the table, do

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

With the answers we can pin down what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what i did was use the second option, the one where the information from the database was correct, and for the footer information i used escape characters `&Oacute;&Ntilde;` maybe not the best solution, but after breaking my head all afternoon i think this one is the easier.