# If $varible == "wierd symbol" like ¤ OR â

Tags: php

My if ($man == "â") or else If ($man == "¤") doesnt work. Cant php read those symbols?

My question is, how can i check If $man = â or ¤

If i `echo 'man = :  ' . $man;` It shows â or ¤

```
echo"<td>";

If ($man == "â"){
print("<img class='sol' src='sad.png'>");
}
else If ($man == "X"){
print("<img class='sol' src='x.png'>");
}
else If ($man == "¤"){
print("<img class='sol' src='sunny.png'>");
}
else 
print("<p class='bigtxt'>$man</p>");

echo "</td>\n";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display special characters in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699037/how-to-display-special-characters-in-php)

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump(urlencode($man), urlencode('â'), urlencode('¤'))`?

Comment: PHP has *no* problems with things like the currency symbol (as long as you're utf-8 all the way through)... but please, please read a PHP coding style guide - this looks like VB with added curly braces and it makes me sad :(

Comment: Output is : string(3) "%E2" string(6) "%C3%A2" string(6) "%C2%A4"

Comment: Your file is (correctly) utf-8-encoded, but your `$man` isn't. The byte `E2` represent the `â` character in the ISO-8859-1 encoding. Where/how did you retrive `$man`? Which encoding do you want use?

Comment: I solved it like this. Thanks to @federkun . $urman = urlencode($man);
and then If ($urman == "%E2")

Comment: Make a answer so i can give u thumbs up

Comment: No, you don't solve anything with that. You just need to be consistent with the encoding, that's how you solve the problem

Comment: There's a reason I wrote *UTF-8 all the way through* : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279 < pretty much the defacto canonical answer for all encoding issues on SO.