# VTIGER CRM (PHP) encoding Vtiger_Util_Helper::toSafeHTML(ZEND_JSON::encode) with characters

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

This is the string which i passing for

```
ZEND_JSON {"0":"265","product":"265","1":"059 K&ouml;nigsblau","st_color":"059 K&ouml;nigsblau","2":"","st_material":"","3":"XL","st_size":"XL","4":"287","stockmanagementid":"287"}
```

I want `059 Königsblau` instead of `059 K&ouml;nigsblau` this string.

This is the actual code in this files `modules/Vtiger/PopupContents.tpl`

Here is Code

```
data-info='{Vtiger_Util_Helper::toSafeHTML(ZEND_JSON::encode($LISTVIEW_ENTRY->getRawData()))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel the header content type issue.This url will help you for resolved the issue

[How to display special characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699037/how-to-display-special-characters-in-php][1])