# EDIT: XAMPP not outputting special characters

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable, sqlsrv

EDIT : I found out that the main reason for my problem is the special characters.

Is there a fix to this? XAMPP is outputting special characters from **SQL Server 2012** as **�**

I tested this code from [How to display special characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699037/how-to-display-special-characters-in-php)

```
<?php
    /*Just for your server-side code*/
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- Your HTML file can still use UTF-8-->
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?= "àè" ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of XAMPP to display output as àè, its displaying Ã Ã¨

Same scenario as for special characters like # and ñ

I'm using Google Chrome.

EDIT: Solved.

**I added `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` to my `sqlsrv` array, and it works perfectly fine.**

Comment: How you solved it, was my first thought... actually.

Comment: It is also showing `Ã Ã¨` without using PHP `<body>àè</body>`