# PHP - convert to html decimal codes while preserving tags

Tags: php, html

I want to convert characters such as

> ```
> <p>Glückwunsch</p>
> ```

to

> ```
> <p>Gl&#252;ckwunsch</p>
> ```

while also preserving html tags.

Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htmlentities in PHP but preserving html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364933/htmlentities-in-php-but-preserving-html-tags)

Comment: Hi, the solution in the mentioned thread will convert to <p>Gl&uuml;ckwunsch</p>. What i need is to be converted to 

    <p>Gl&#252;ckwunsch</p>

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be something like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node ){
    $node->textContent = htmlentities($node->textContent);
}
$string = $dom->saveXML($dom);
```

This way you can avoid messing up content like: 
`<p> We know that 2 &lt; 4</p>`